# jQuery do something when function returns something different

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to do an action when a function returns a different result?

I do not want to add unnecessary code into this function:

```
function numCols() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if(winWidth >= 1900){
        return 4;
    } else if(winWidth >= 1025 && winWidth <= 1899){
        return 3;
    } else if(winWidth >= 600 && winWidth <= 1024){
        return 2;
    } else if(winWidth <= 599){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But instead, I would like to be able to do other functions when `numCols()` returns a different number.  I would put `numCols()` into a window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    numCols()
});
```

then I would like to do other functions when numCols() returns a different number.  Only when it returns a number and not the whole time the window is being resized.

Comment: You could pass a parameter and change the values it returns based on the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing the following:

On document load save in a global variable the initial amount of columns:

```
$(function(){
    window.columnNum = numCols();
});
```

Then in your resize handler do:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var currentCols = numCols(); // get the current amount of cols
    if(currentCols != window.columnNum){ // execute the following code only if the number of columns have changed
        window.columnNum = currentCols;
        doSomethingElseHere(); // add any code here
    }
});
```

Comment: No sorry, I thought I acted too quickly.

Comment: just as a comment for the rest - This shows how to change code when the number of columns changes, not necessarily a different code for each number

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var cols = numCols();
    if (cols == 1) {
        // call my custom function
        myCustomFunction();
    } else if (cols == 2) {
        // call another function
        anotherFunction();
    } else {
        aThirdFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but I will have to make an If statement for every number. There could potentially be an unlimited amount of numbers. The above example is just a quick example

Comment: While there in theory could be an unlimited number of column options, it's probably unrealistic to have more than 24 (the most any grid system I've used supports). Alternately, since I don't know what you're doing in the custom function, you could just pass the custom function the column count as a parameter.

Comment: I could, though the above example was just a snippet of code that got my point across, I will be using the same syntax, though I won't be using it for columns.  All I really needed to know is _when_ the `numCols()` changed, not specifically to what.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario your function return values, and yes you can operate with that value and you can make same other things..

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if(parseInt(numCols()))
   {
     alert('first action');
   }
});
```

**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdSDR/1/)**

Comment: This is a great idea also, but I will have to make an If statement for every number.  There could potentially be an unlimited amount of numbers.  The above example is just a quick example

Comment: I did edit on the fiddle just if someone want to see different solution, so in this case whenever you resize the window `if(parseInt(numCols()))` will try to parse the returning value and if it is true, there is room for other actions